# Visualizing google analytics data in React.js, editing json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-visualization, google-analytics-api, recharts

I'm pulling data from google analytics to display on a user dashboard. this is my first visualization project in React and I decided to use recharts for the vizualization. However, I want to reformat some of the google analytics data so that it looks pretty such as the date.

I am struggling to write a function that goes through my data array and reformat the data 201903 for example into 03, 2019 (or even better March, 2019). I just need a function that can do that. however, I am not experienced in pulling that kind of data from an array.

Here is my Data:

```
[ [ '201811', '1', 'DailyPrep', '2' ],
  [ '201812', '1', 'DailyPrep', '64' ],
  [ '201901', '1', 'DailyPrep', '220' ],
  [ '201902', '1', 'DailyPrep', '755' ],
  [ '201903', '1', 'DailyPrep', '8534' ],
  [ '201904', '1', 'DailyPrep', '4705' ],
  [ '201905', '1', 'DailyPrep', '3667' ] ]
```

an example of a function I am looking for is:

```
Const FormatX = () => {
   //year = the first four digits of the first data item in each array
   //month = the last two digits of the first data item in each array
   //monthyr = month + ', ' + year;
   //return monthyr;
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of how you want the final data to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for a date formatter you can try moment.js

```
moment("201905", "YYYYMM").format("MMMM YYYY");
// Output: May 2019
```

With the data you posted you might run into an issue with recharts because it only accepts arrays that have objects in them (not arrays like in your example). You will need to map the arrays to an object.

```
const mapped = data.map(v => { return { date: v[0], someValue: v[3] } })
```

I put your example in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheSwedishChef/x4uz5jkf/26/), hope that helps.